# Adding Dependencies to my Java API

Tags: java

I am newbie to Java and I have written an API and I would like to distribute it. I am creating a Jar file to make an API, but my program uses some other API's like Jena and XSOM. How do I include these API's to my Jar distribution with the help of Eclipse? I have read the similar questions but couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not clarified. It depends on distributing for different purpose.

If you can not make it clear, just pick up some tools to do it:

- How about **fatjar** ? It just add any dependencies JARs into one jar, you can do it from export executable jar from eclipse menu.
- How about [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) ? It eases dependency management for any java project, but learning how to use it will take some time.
- How about build tools ? For example, [Apache ANT](http://ant.apache.org/) just a make-like tool designed for java project. Unlike maven, it assembles project building in any sequence you want.
- How about [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/) ? It packages your project into executable files.

  *Do forget contains licenses. When you distribute 3rd-party JARs, license declaration should distribute as well.*

Anyway, there are many purpose for distributing. For example, preparing dependencies for deploying and running in web container. Usually, we have deploy tool (ant task or maven plugin provided by web container provider). For example, preparing dependencies for a standalone java application. In such case, we should make deploy tool and consider process by self:

- How the application ship to production environment ? Download by url, copy by scp, checkout from release branch in the git repo ?
- How to update the application on the production ? It is important problem, when you go into trouble, quickly fix and hot deploy is needed.
- What is the better order about the JARs in the classpath ? Wrong order will cause class shadowing or load wrong configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

You some how need to add the dependent jars to the classpath.

You could either:

- list the other jars as dependencies and just instruct users of your
  "api" to add them to their classpath.
- If your "api" involves a main class and you want to distribute it as an executable jar you could distribute your jar with an external folder that includes the required libraries and then alter your jar manifest to specify your main class and classpath to include those [external dependencies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html).
- If you use maven, then by listing them in your dependencies then they will automatically be included for the client code, as they would be deemed as being [transitive dependencies.](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies)
- Shade the jars - so include them by unpackaging their contents and including them in your jar. There are three ways that spring to mind for this*:

  - If you are building your api in maven you could look at the [shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)
  - You could look at using the somewhat amusingly named (?!) [Jar Jar Links](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/)
  - The eclipse "export as executable jar" allows you to save an ant file that does similar functionlity.

(*In any of these cases, it depends on the licenses of the dependent libraries as to whether they allow you to do this)
 -

Comment: I don't want to create an executable jar file. I don't have any main class. I want to create a jar file that will be used by others just like the APIs I used. But I need to add these APIs to my jar file so that people don't have to add those APIs one by one in order use my API.

Comment: So you want to shade the jars - or go down the maven route.